# Flying Saucer PDF Rendering CSS 3 column-count not working

Tags: css, grails, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I am using grails with the `flying saucer pdf renderer(9.0.4)` with `grails`.

I am trying to render a table in a similar fashion as the `CSS 3.0` attribute column-count does it. The table itself is rather slim and i need it to use three columns on my page.

This could be done easily by using the column-count attribute as defined by `CSS 3.0` but this is currently not supported by `flying saucer (itext)`.

My table is very simple and looks like this

```
 <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>header 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Value 1
          </td>
          <td>
            Value 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

The structure is very simple but my table has more than 1k rows. 
So i need this table to use multiple columns per page or it will result in a very large pdf document. And since the table has only two columns its a waste of space.

I am very grateful for any hints on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... sorry for necropost... Maybe it'll help someone else... Your answer lay in other theme - html&css markup... You can try use not table but div's or other html blocks in manner:

```
<...>
<div style="display:inline-block; width: 40%"><!-- data column -->
   <span styly="display:inline-block; width: 30%">column 1</span>
   <span styly="display:inline-block; width: 70%">column 2</span>
</div>
```

So such div's will place by 2 (according to width as 40% of available row width) at single row